# Parse multiline output with bash

Tags: bash, grep, tor

I have a program that will create a text file with output which looks like this:

```bsh
...
AF
Aug 05 16:27:01.310 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1c, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
Aug 05 16:27:01.310 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 05 16:27:01.311 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 05 16:27:01.314 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 05 16:27:01.314 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 05 16:27:01.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 05 16:27:01.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 05 16:27:01.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Aug 05 16:27:01.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Aug 05 16:27:11.000 [notice] Catching signal TERM, exiting cleanly.

AX
Aug 05 16:27:11.333 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1c, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
Aug 05 16:27:11.333 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 05 16:27:11.333 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 05 16:27:11.338 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 05 16:27:11.338 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 05 16:27:11.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 05 16:27:11.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 05 16:27:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Aug 05 16:27:12.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Aug 05 16:27:21.000 [notice] Catching signal TERM, exiting cleanly.
...
```

Essentially, it'll check whether TOR can connect via different countries. I made it so it outputs the ISO alpha-2 code before the paragraph, and then an empty return line.

How can I create a program which can parse each individual paragraph, search for the text '100%', and if it exists, copy the alpha-2 code (above the paragraph) into a different file, using bash '>>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input consists of records that are separated by one or more blank lines, then you can use awk or perl in *paragraph mode*

```
awk -vRS= '/100%/ {print $1}' file >> newfile
```

or

```
perl -00anE 'say $F[0] if /100%/' file >> newfile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, awk was exactly what i needed! If you have a minute, would you mind explaining in a couple words what the vRS options are, and $1, does that represent the 2nd entry in each paragraph (the country code)?